# Change GIT status file color android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, color-scheme

**TLDR** : How to change following files color in android studio

[image]

The other day I was playing with [Color Themes](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) , and Material Theme plugin to see which colors and themes  would look better for android studio . I finally realized the native color and theme were best for me .

Befor changing color I exported all my setting for backup . So finally after realizing I imported back my settings . Every thing changed back to normal except these git status color . I tried to change color via setting but could not find the property .

How can I change these color back to native color ?

Comment: Try to reopen your project or make another project and copy this on it

Comment: No use of that  , I found solution and posted below

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution

It's in `Version Control` > `File Status Colors`

[image]

Comment: After every restart of AS, colors going back to this (blue) color again. How to keep my changes permanent? Do you also having same issue

Comment: May be some plugin is causing them to revert, please check.